# Существует ли возможность сделать символы, вводимые в prompt неотображаемыми?

Tags: javascript, html, css, prompt

Всем привет! Есть переменная request, определяющая логику программы. С программой работает несколько человек сразу: все видят монитор, но только один знает, какой комбинацией клавиш вызвать prompt и какой код нужно ввести для изменения переменной request. Нужно скрыть вводимые в prompt символы, чтобы управляющие коды оставались секретом для участников игры. Пробовал для этих целей использовать input type="hidden", но программа неожиданно стала глючить, выдавая разные результаты при вводе одних и тех же символов на разных устройствах. Может быть, кто-то подскажет решение? (на крайний случай, подойдут даже костыли вроде миниатюрного шрифта или "цвет шрифта = цвету фона")

Comment: В prompt не скрыть данных, а если вызвать f12 то, если нет бэка обработчика данных, то можно будет увидеть все коды. Привидите ваш пример кода, и поясните, какого именно поведения вы хотите достичь

Comment: Как вообще связан prompt, который видим всем и input hidden - который невидим тоже для всех?

Comment: Можно использовать input type=password ...... но как написали выше - любой может на клиенте посмотреть код обработчика в т.ч. этого самого request.... что явно небезопасно

Comment: Да, примерно такой эффект я и обнаружил к своему несказанному удивлению: когда после ввода кода в input и нажатия на enter у меня открылась новая вкладка браузера с полным исходным js-кодом, я испытал такую гамму чувств!.. Теперь ищу безопасную альтернативу